# Channel Advisor / Ebay Image quality Issue

Tags: javascript, html, image, replace

If I have a image src on my HTML as follow:

```
http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NzgwWDc4MA==/z/FrMAAOSweW5U3QvN/$_12.JPG?set_id=880000500F
```

and I want to change all $_12.JPG to $_57.JPG in order to get the better image quality like below:

```
http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NzgwWDc4MA==/z/FrMAAOSweW5U3QvN/$_57.JPG?set_id=880000500F
```

How do I do this with Javascript so that it replaces all $_12.JPG on my HTML with $_57.JPG?

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: How are the images inserted on your page? Are you using an API or manually inserting them but don't want to change each image one by one? Please display some relevant source code so we have something to work with, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the URL using `.replace()` for example:

```
document.getElementById('TheImage').src.replace('$_12.JPG','$_57.JPG');
```

Here is a small demo so you can see this in action.

---

**Demo Source Code**

---

```js
function URLswap(){
    //--Set image variable
    var curlink=document.getElementById('ebay');
    //--Replace unwanted sting with new string.
    var Newlink=curlink.src.replace('$_12.JPG','$_57.JPG');
    //---Set new src
    curlink.src=Newlink;
    //-- Display new src (text) in div
    document.getElementById('currentlink').innerHTML='New Src= '+Newlink;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="URLswap()">Change</button><br>
<div id="currentlink">Current Src= http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NzgwWDc4MA==/z/FrMAAOSweW5U3QvN/$_12.JPG?set_id=880000500F</div>
<img id="ebay" src="http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NzgwWDc4MA==/z/FrMAAOSweW5U3QvN/$_12.JPG?set_id=880000500F"/>
```

For multiple image you can give those images a `class` and use a for loop to apply this to all images with that class but since you don't have any source code in your question or any mention of `id` / `class` I'm just keeping the answer as basic as the question.

I hope this helps. Happy coding!